# How to insert cyrillic-based text to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, utf, cyrillic

Somehow, when I insert Cyrillic data to my database column called address(Varchar 40), it just inserts it halfway, and the other half is lost.
But then when I checked the source of my page while retrieving the data, I saw the Cyrillic text has been saved as some kind of encoding..

For example: "улица отец паисий" is saved as & #1091;& #1083; & #1086;& #1090;& #1077;& #1094; & #1087;& #1072;& #1080;& #1089;& #1080;& #1081;" without the space between & and #.

I tried saving the same text to another column, which is of type text and I had no problems.

How can I fix this so that I could enter the text value in my address column in the database?

Answer (score 0):

You should set UTF8 encoding for your webpage. As well when initializing connection to your database use `"SET NAMES UTF8;"` query